# Redux Saga Blocking

Tags: react-native, redux, generator, redux-saga

I'm new to Redux Saga and generators in general so am trying to wrap my head around how to "await" a dispatched action before executing the rest of code after the dispatch.

For example:

```
    // Sideeffect to load messages on mount
    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;

        if(mounted) {
            dispatch({ type: 'GET_THREAD_MESSAGES', threadId: _id })
            setIsLoading(false);
        }

        return () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_FOCUSSED_MESSAGES' })
        }
    }, [])
```

When the component first mounts it will dispatch `GET_THREAD_MESSAGES`.  I watch for said action in my `rootSaga` with the following:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        ...
        watchGetThreadMessages(),
        watchClearFocussedMessages()
    ])
}
```

My applicable sagas:

```
export function* watchGetThreadMessages() {
    yield takeEvery('GET_THREAD_MESSAGES', getThreadMessages)
}

export function* getThreadMessages({ threadId, lastDate }) {
    const { token } = yield select(state => state.auth);

    try {
        const { data } = yield call(getMessages, token, threadId)

        yield put({
            type: 'GET_THREAD_MESSAGES_SUCCESS',
            allMessages: data.messages,
            totalMessages: data.count
        })

        console.log('retrieved messages')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

`getMessages` is an axios call to my endpoint getting data from the server.  The issue is that my `setIsLoading` after the component mount `dispatch` will fire before I am done fetching my messages from the axios call as it is asynchronous.  Normally if I was fetching the data inside the component I would just await this response but am unsure how to await a `dispatch` action.  I've gotten around it by passing my setIsLoading to the dispatch and firing the setIsLoading inside the saga but that isn't the most elegant solution and would like to know a better process if there is one.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Any are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you actions are just plain synchronous functions, there is no way to track `isLoading` state inside a component. You have to keep `isLoading` in redux store instead, and connect to your component. Whenever `GET_THREAD_MESSAGES_SUCCESS` action is dispatched, reducer will change `isLoading` value to `false`. For example:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// isLoading prop is mapped to state.messages.isLoading
function YourComponent({ isLoading, dispatch }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_THREAD_MESSAGES', threadId: 'someId' });
  }, []);

  if(isLoading) {
    return <div>Some loader</div>;
  }

  return <div>Your component</div>;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isLoading: state.messages.isLoading,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Your messages reducer may look like the following:

```js
export default function messagesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_THREAD_MESSAGES':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case 'GET_THREAD_MESSAGES_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        allMessages: action.allMessages,
        totalMessages: action.totalMessages,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I had a fealing that may have been the solution but wanted to make sure before I went crazy adding all this state to my redux store.  Thank you.